# copy of sugarcrm (or in general: copy of project) not working

Tags: php, netbeans, copy, xampp, sugarcrm

I'm working on a sugarcrm project (it's a free crm system).
I've developed on my own machine with xampp and netbeans. My local copy works fine, but if I try to copy it to a second machine, some of my customizations don't work any more.

What I tried:
- `sqldump` of the used database. Executed it on the second machine. By a quick inspection, everything seems to be copied.
- copied the project folder of `installdir/xampp/htdocs/myproject` to `installdir/xampp/htdocs/myproject` on the second machine

Obviously, I have to overseen something. I also compared the `php.ini` of both machines. The login credentials for the db are the same (`root@localhost`).

And ideas what I've missed? Thank you!

Comment: I might have found the solution. Apparently, I needed to run the sugarcrm "repair rebuild" feature...most things work now. An interesting bug remains: after saving some objects, a popup window appears to set certain parameters...

Comment: Are you deploying on localhost of other machine, which server do you use xampp or wamp ? Or you are deploying on server ?

Comment: Hi, im using xampp on both machines. the deployment to the server happens later via svn, but thats not important right now.